# Debug Windows Mobile unit-tests in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, debugging, windows-mobile

I started Windows Mobile 6.x development but I am facing a problem when I want to unit-test my  classes.
In fact when I run the tests everything goes like it should: VS launches the emulator and then runs the tests. But when I try to debug them, it launches emulator, runs the tests but my breakpoint are never hit. It seems that debugging is just running the tests normally.

Does anybody has already met this problem ?

Thanks.

NB : Debugging applications in emulator or on a WM device works fine, it justs happens in unit-tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply [the way the smart device unit test framework works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513875.aspx), and it sucks.  [I blogged about my workaround](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/11/20/DebuggingSmartDeviceMSTESTUnitTests.aspx) just last week.

Comment: Thanks for these informations. Manual debugging, I never though I would have to do this in 2009...
Your website seems to be temporarly unavailable, I will get a look to this workaround as soon as it is up.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try that tonight, but it seems great :-)